# How do I redirect the first request from devices on my local network to a specified page?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, redirection

How would I go about redirecting the first request from devices on my local network to a page I have set up? I've heard of VPNs, proxies, and DNS servers, but I don't know which work / is the best option. The solutions I've found don't redirect once, they redirect all the time, so I'm looking for a finer level of control.

[Spoiler alert for the BBC Sherlock, oddly enough.]

Context: Halloween is coming up for those in the USA, and my house is hosting a party. I'm planning to be in costume as Moriarty from Sherlock. The last time we saw this wonderful archvillain of a character, he took over all the screens in London with an annoying "Didja miss me? Didja miss me?" Now naturally, I can't do that, so the next closest I have is to redirect their web requests when they first try and access the web. Furthermore, I'd like to do it in good humor, so breaking all internet access isn't the best idea. Hence redirecting the first request to an autoplaying video or gif with sound.

Hardware available: I have a Netgear N600 router, a Linux / Windows laptop, three Android devices and an Arduino Yun.

Comment: Your question doesn't need to contain the page text... that's unimportant... what you're looking for is a "captive portal". When a device connects to a wireless network and someone tries to go to the internet they are shown a page which (often) requires a sign in or to purchase "air time" to use the Internet :)

Answer (score 0):

Its called **"captive portal"** you can make that with different methods.

- First method by flashing your router with dd-wrt firmware and using the new additional options to set up Landing page. [Check here for more info](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Captive_Portal)
- The second method by using a router built for that like [UBNT routers.](https://www.ubnt.com/)
- The last method by building RADIAS server, a PC will be connected to your network, and any access will be redirect to that server.

or you can find third party firmware like [sputnik](http://sputnik.com/).

Comment: Well radius does not do captive portal. It can only help with managing user session. OP will need CoovaChilli or ChilliSpot or WiFiDog on the AP(dd-wrt or OpenWRT) or a Linux PC to do captive portal.